# Как в Indy Imap пометить письма как прочтенные?

Tags: delphi, indy, imap, email

Подключаюсь к почтовому ящику по IMAP, все нормально, получаю количество писем в папке "Входящие" ("INBOX"), могу их прочитать. Но есть проблема - метод **Retrieve** не помечает письма как прочитанные, и при следующем чтении почты эти письма я вижу вновь как непрочтенные - соответственно и загружаются они наравне с новыми.
В интернете нашел описание метода, написано что именно **Retrieve** помечает письма после загрузки как прочтенные (чтобы письма не помечались как прочтенные есть метод **RetrievePeek**).

Вот код процедуры:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MsgCnt, i: integer;
  msg: TIdMessage;
begin
  try
    msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    msg.CharSet := 'windows-1251';
    msg.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset="windows-1251"';

    IdIMAP41.Host := 'imap.gmail.com';
    IdIMAP41.Port := 993;
    IdIMAP41.Username := '***@gmail.com';
    IdIMAP41.Password := '*****';

    IdIMAP41.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdIMAP41);
    IdIMAP41.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;

    IdIMAP41.Connect;

    IdIMAP41.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
    MsgCnt := IdIMAP41.MailBox.TotalMsgs;
    ShowMessage('Кол-во писем в ящике: ' + IntToStr(MsgCnt));

    for i := 1 to MsgCnt do
    begin
      IdIMAP41.Retrieve(i, msg);
      if msg.Subject = 'Need' then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(msg.Subject);
        Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(msg.Body);        
      end;

    end;

    IdIMAP41.Disconnect;
    IdIMAP41.IOHandler.Free;

  except
    on e: Exception do
      ShowMessage('ошибка чтения писем!');
  end;

end;
```

Надеюсь кто-то сталкивался с Indy IMAP и подскажет что делать.

Answer (score 1):

Автор и все у кого такая ошибка- обратите внимание на версию Инди.
У меня стоит инди 10 на Делфи 7-ке. все работает- код жизнеспособен и сообщения отмечаются как прочитанные. Тест на mail.ru прошел.
и еще for i := 1 to MsgCnt do будет смотреть письма начиная со старых.
а for i := MsgCnt downto 1 do будет смотреть с последних полученных и к более старым.

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то не могу написать комментарий,напишу в ответ.
Попробуйте ящик на другом почтовом сервере mail.ru, hotmail.com и т.д.
У гугла могут быть свои заморочки, почтовый клиент оперы всегда глючил с их ящиками.

Comment: Когда проблема появилась, сразу же попробовал с yandex почтой -  тоже самое. Письма каждый раз все считаются новыми.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать не 
`IdIMAP41.MailBox.TotalMsgs`
а
`IdIMAP41.MailBox.RecentMsgs`.
Тогда показывает количество последних присланных писем.